# Male alien searching for a girlfriend on Earth

Tags: identify-this-movie, comedy

I'd like to know what the title is. I don't remember much about this movie, but I'll try my best.

- I watched it in late 90's - early 2000's
- It's in English language
- Its genre is maybe a comedy
- It's a Hollywood movie, I think
- There are many clones of the man (not really sure)
- The alien spaceship is round/sphere (not really sure)

This is THE ONLY scene I remember:

The man (Alien) is having a dinner with a woman. Suddenly, his (sorry) penis is vibrating uncontrollably (making noises). I think the alien has no penis and replaced it with some mechanical one. But, I also think it's some kind of communication device.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the sci-fi comedy [What Planet Are You From?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/What_Planet_Are_You_From%3F) from 2000 starring the late Garry Shandling, Annette Bening and many other known names.

> A denizen (Garry Shandling) of a faraway planet occupied only by highly evolved males is ordered by his superior, Graydon (Ben Kingsley), to find a female human, impregnate her and bring the baby back to the planet [...] and meets Susan (Annette Bening), a recovering alcoholic. [...] Susan finds herself wildly satisfied by Harold, even though **men from his planet have no genitals and he has been equipped for his Earth visit with a penis that makes a loud whirring sound whenever he gets an erection.**

It happens when they go out to dinner, too. You can briefly see this scene in the trailer around 0:57: